# Equation of a parabola with vertex $V$ and point $P$

Tags: conic-sections

> Find the equation of the parabola which has the given vertex $V$, which passes through the given point $P$, and which has the specified axis of symmetry.
>
> $V(4,-2), P(2,14)$, vertical axis of symmetry.

The answer is $(x-4)^2=\frac 14(y+2)$, but I do not know how to get this answer. I know it is an upward facing parabola with $x=4$ as the axis of symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find a parabola of the form
$$(x-4)^2 = 4p (y+2)$$
If you replace $x=2$ and $y=14$ en the last equation, you will find $p=\frac{1}{16}$. So that,
$$(x-4)^2 = \frac{1}{4} (y+2)$$
is the parabola you are looking for.